# Why this program wont break out of the loop and ask for input?

Tags: c

I have following code:

```
badinput:
scanf("%d", choice);
switch (choice){
case 1:
...
case 2:
...
case 3:
...
default: {print("try again");goto badinput;}
}
```

When I put 1 2 or 3 its ok when i input text, for example "a" program wont stop at next `scanf`. What is the problem here

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't get past the `goto`. Yuk.

Comment: Because you most probably don't have the `break`s in the `case` statements...

Comment: @MrLister You don't have to, it's the last statement :)

Comment: `scanf("%d"` does not read `"a"`.  The next time you call `scanf("%d",`, that `"a"` is still there.  Need to read it by other means. to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter the character `a` as your input, `scanf` fails but it also leaves `a` in the input stream. You'll have to clear the stream before trying to read more data.

```
badinput:
scanf("%d", &choice);  // That needs to be &choice, not choice
switch (choice){
   case 1:
      ...
   case 2:
         ...
   case 3:
            ...
   default: {clearStream(stdin); print("try again");goto badinput;}
}
```

where `clearStream` can be defined as:

```
void clearStream(FILE* in)
{
   int c;
   while ( (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```

If `choice` is the only thing entered in that line, you can use `fgets` to read the entire line and then try to extract `choice` from it.

```
char line[20];  // Make it as large as you need

badinput:
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &choice) == 1 )
{
   switch (choice){
      case 1:
         ...
      case 2:
            ...
      case 3:
               ...
      default: {print("try again");goto badinput;}
   }
}
else
{ 
   print("try again");
   goto badinput;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` fails, but this code does not use the result of `scanf()` to detect that failure.  It is UB that the `default` was called.

Comment: but again, the loop won't break if the `switch` construct is falling through to the `goto` statement..

Answer (score 1):

> program wont break out of the loop and ask for input

**Reason :**

The problem is that, the character you entered into `scanf()` remains in the input stream, making you omit future `scanf()` function calls.

**You can avoid this by consuming the character.**

---

**Solution :**

One way of doing this is:

- declare a `char` variable

```
char bad;
```

- and changing `default` case of `switch` to:

```
default:
{
    scanf("%c",&bad); //without bad use just scanf("%c"); but it gives warning
    printf("try again");
    goto badinput;
}
```